# Get JUST the string value from a table row in powershell

Tags: string, powershell

i was wondering, as the title say. how to get just the string from a row in a powershell table.

so to simplify it, lets say i have a variable called `$Fruits`
that returns this:

```
Fuits                   
-----                   
Banana
Apple
Watermelon
Peach
Pineapple
```

How would i go about printing **JUST** the word "Apple"?
i know i can use `$Fruits[1]`, however that returns another table.

```
Fuits                   
-----                   
Apple
```

How would i get **JUST** the word apple from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were 99.99% there.

You just need to select the specific column so that only its text is returned instead of an object.

So this `$Fruits[1].Fuits`

**Other examples**

```
# A single one
$Fruits[1].Fuits

#3 first records
$Fruits[0..2].Fuits
#OR
$Fruits | Select -First 3 -ExpandProperty Fuits

# All the records 
$Fruits | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fuits
#OR
$Fruits.Fuits
```

Datasource used:

```
  $Fruits = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Fuits = 'Banana' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{Fuits = 'Apple' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{Fuits = 'Watermelon' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{Fuits = 'Peach' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{Fuits = 'Pineapple' }
  )
```

Comment: Awesome! thanku. i feel kinda stupid now ngl.

Comment: If i then want to `foreach` loop the original table. and `write-host "this fruit is called: $Fruits[$i].Fruits` would i then use `foreach($Fruits.Fuits in $Fruits)` ?

Comment: @Elly `Foreach ($F in $Fruits.Fuits)` and then `write-host "this fruit is called: $F"` or  `Foreach ($F in $Fruits)` and then `Write-Host "this fruit is called: $($F.fuits)"`, the latter being useful if you had multiple properties you might want to access.

Comment: again thanku! this helped me a lot! :)